# how to convert whole html file with multiple pages into pdf using python( already use pdfkit module)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, task

I tried the pdfkit module of Python, but only the first page is converted into pdf, and the desired identical output is not obtained.

I tried the pdfkit module along with config and options, but I am not getting proper output.
I am expecting identical HTML file pages to be converted into PDF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.